# input validation for number between 0 and 100?

Tags: laravel

I have to validate an integer which is not required or necessary but if it is entered, it must between 0 and 100 
Actually I have to enter score value ranging 0 to 100
I tried 'digits_between:1,2' but value 0 and 100 cannot be entered
any help?

Comment: Share possible values  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from Laravel 5.6 docs, validation [rule between](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-between) & [rule nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-nullable)

```
$request->validate([
    'field_name' => 'nullable|integer|between:0,100',
]);
```

if you want to accept `float` values as well, use [rule numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-numeric)

```
$request->validate([
    'field_name' => 'nullable|numeric|between:0,100',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved but please correct me can we enter value 0 in database becoz value 0 is not being entered thanks

Comment: @Amir yes, it's possible to store 0 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ([docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-between)).

```
[
  'number' => 'sometimes|integer|between:0,100'
]
```

Comment: `sometimes` is not needed here, what about float ?

Comment: `sometimes` is used where field is not always present

Answer (score 0):

You can just use validation for condition without `required`

```
 "field_name" => 'numeric|between:0,99.99',
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the full line of code

```
$v = Validator::make($data, ['field' => 'numeric|between:0,99.99']);
```